# How do I query a deep relationship in laravel and filter parents by children?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

For example, if a category has many products which has many skus, how do I get all products that have a sku with a price greater than 10?

This returns all the categories but only has the expected skus attached, where I want only the categories that have said skus.

```
$category = new Category();
$category->with(array('products', 'products.skus' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('price', '>', 10);
}))->get();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're looking for is `whereHas()`. Also you can write `with(array('products.skus'))` directly without `products`

```
$category = new Category();
$categories = $category->with(array('products', 'products.skus' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('price', '>', 10);
    }))
    ->whereHas('products.skus', function($query){
        $query->where('price', '>', 10);
    })->get();
```

You need both, `with` and `whereHas` but you can simplify the code a bit by putting the closure in a variable:

```
$priceGreaterTen = function($query){
    $query->where('price', '>', 10);
};

$category = new Category();
$categories = $category->with(array('products', 'products.skus' => $priceGreaterTen))
                       ->whereHas('products.skus', $priceGreaterTen)
                       ->get();
```

Comment: I keep getting `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::products.skus()`

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Laravel? The support for nested relations in `whereHas` has only been enabled recently. Run `composer udpate`

Comment: Okay, I am still on 4.1 Hopefully upgrading won't break everything.

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 5, try this

```
$category = Category::with(['products','products.skus'])->whereHas('products.skus', function($query) {
    $query->where('price', '>', 10);
})->get();
```